# Batch merging PDF files based on file name

Tags: batch, pdf, printing, merge, pdftk

I'm trying to find a program/script that can merge files based on the filename.
Files are in 1 folder (output from PDF24 print to PDF) and names as the following example:

File name layout: `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS file name.pdf`

Examples:

```
2021-05-31 11-12-13 Microsoft Outlook - Memo Style.pdf
2021-05-31 11-12-15 Some another filename - string.pdf
2021-05-31 11-12-18 Some another filename - string.pdf
2021-05-31 11-12-25 Some another filename - string.pdf
2021-05-31 11-12-45 Some another filename - string.pdf
2021-05-31 11-13-21 Microsoft Outlook - Memo Style.pdf
```

---

What I want is that the program looks at the filename, and takes every file from 'Microsoft Outlook' (including Outlook) until the next 'Microsoft Outlook' (excluding) and merges them.

What I'm doing is I'm printing an Outlook file and (some of) its attachments, and I want to merge them, so every PDF file is a mail on page 1, and has its attachments on the following pages.

Requirements:

- Important here is that the attachments are in the correct order, ie ordered by date, oldest first
- I want the PDF files to be split by mail. Every PDF file after merging is 1 file and its attachments
- I actually prefer a manual script because it has to run about once a week or once every few days
- Output should be automatically saved to a folder I choose (a subfolder of the source folder)
- I don't really care about output file names. They can be 001, 002, ... for example

I've looked at PDFtk after finding some questions on here, but it either can't do it, or I don't understand the documentation well enough (a very real possibility).

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Merging every single PDF in 1 giant file is something I can do already, but I'd like them split because I can print and staple them automatically that way. Call me... energy efficient.
Merging first and splitting afterward could be a possibility too I guess.

Comment: What program would you use to merge them all in one file?. Can it be called from the terminal?

Comment: @ComputerUser121212 [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) (from the tags/original question) can merge PDF documents from the command line (whether or not they are currently using it).

Comment: To merge al docs in 1 file, I'd use Foxit PhantomPDF or PDF24. They cannot be called from terminal afaik.
I could try and use PDFtk indeed to do this, but I'd still have to figure out how to split afterwards based on content if I try to merge all first and split afterwards.
Or figure out how to merge on file name.

Answer (score 1):

The following Python code should do the trick. The code runs on Python 3.9 and uses PDFtk. It assumes the first file in your directory is one that contains "Microsoft Outlook"

```python
import os

files = os.listdir(".")
files.sort()

command_prefix = "pdftk "
command_args = ""
command_end = "cat output output1.pdf"
counter = 0

for file in files:
  if ".py" not in file:
    if "Microsoft Outlook" in file:
      if files.index(file) != 0:
        os.system(command_prefix + command_args + command_end)
      counter = counter + 1
      command_args = '"' + file + '"' + " "
      command_end = "cat output output" + str(counter) + ".pdf"
    else:
      command_args = command_args + '"' + file + '"' + " "

os.system(command_prefix + command_args + command_end)
```

Save it to a file and run it from within the same directory as your files

Comment: I'll try that first thing tomorrow. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, I tried your script, but it doesn't seem to work perfecly. I named the file _com.py, and it gave the following output:

`V:\>python _com.py
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   zzz.py
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.`

I renamed the file to zzz.py, as per your comment about the first file having to be an Outlook print, but the same thing happened.

I DID get output, but the output1.pdf was missing its Outlook print. The 2nd one was correctn and there should have been a 3rd one, but that didn't show up.

Comment: To add a general remark: it also has trouble with subfolders, though I can mitigate this by moving the subfolder. Which i did before above testing.

Comment: @Juno Thank you for your coments. I'm sorry, for I had made some mistakes. The code should work now, assuming no subdirectories and that the first file is one that contains "Microsoft Outlook" (excluding the python script). Let me know if you have any other issues

Comment: That works like a CHARM! I'm eternally grateful to you!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: I've made your script into a bat file with some Googling. For anyone who is interested, here it is:

`@echo on
rem = """

python -x "%~f0" %*
echo some more batch commands
goto :eof

"""
# Anything here is interpreted by Python

import os`

(etc)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script

Comment: One little bug I just encountered: The script doesn't process the last 'outlook' print and its files.

But thanks again, I just processed 34 PDF's (should have been 35) in not even 1 minute.

Comment: Are you sure you have pasted the last line? That is the one in charge of processing the last one. By the way, Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Comment: Hi, sorry for the super late reply. I just tried again and only 2 of the 3 merged PDF files were generated.

Comment: I just tried it on my machine I was able to verify that the script does in fact call pdftk for all files, including the last one. However, it is the last line which does that, so make sure you have copied it.

Comment: Ok I've tried again and you're right. If I use the method of opening CMD and execute the python script, it works flawlessly. However, if I use my bat file, the code doesn't work for some weird reason. The last file gets skipped. I've compared the code in both file and it is identical. Strange.

Comment: You can always [compile the Python file to an .exe](https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/).

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the code ComputerUser121212 posted works perfectly.

I've made it into a batch file, using the following link as help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script

I'm not proficient in batch files so my code may be suboptimal, but it works.

```
    @echo on
rem = """

python -x "%~f0" %*
echo some more batch commands
goto :eof

"""
# Anything here is interpreted by Python

import os

files = os.listdir(".")
files.sort()

command_prefix = "pdftk "
command_args = ""
command_end = "cat output output1.pdf"
counter = 0

for file in files:
  if ".py" not in file:
    if "Microsoft Outlook" in file:
      if files.index(file) != 0:
        os.system(command_prefix + command_args + command_end)
      counter = counter + 1
      command_args = '"' + file + '"' + " "
      command_end = "cat output output" + str(counter) + ".pdf"
    else:
      command_args = command_args + '"' + file + '"' + " "

os.system(command_prefix + command_args + command_end)
```

Paste the code above in a Notepad, save as a .bat file inside the pdf folder, and done.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to using a pure bat to do the same job...

```bath
@echo off 

Setlocal EnabledelayeDexpansion

set "_in_dir=Full\Path\To\your\pdf\Files\Folder"
set "_out_dir=Full\Path\To\Some\Temp\Folder\Output"

2>nul mkdir "!_out_dir!" & cd /d "!_in_dir!"
set _cnt=<nul & set "_results=!_in_dir!\output.pdf" 

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir /od /a:a /b "*Microsoft?Outlook*.pdf"
')do set /a "_cnt+=1" && call %:^) "%%~fi" "000!_cnt!" "!_out_dir!"

pushd "Full\Path\To\your\pdfTK\Folder\bin"
pdftk.exe "!_out_dir!\*.pdf" cat output "!_results!"

%:^) 
if not "%~nx1"=="" (set "_new=%~2" & call move "%~1" "%~3\!_new:~-4!.pdf"
     exit /b) else (rmdir /s /q "!_out_dir!\." & popd & endlocal & goto :eOf)
```

---

**1)** Edite this script for add/set the variables to their respective paths that you will use in the bat process and also *the pertinent full path to `pdfTK.exe` folder*:

```bath
set "_in_dir=Full\Path\To\your\pdf\Files\Folder"
set "_out_dir=Full\Path\To\Some\Temp\Folder\Output"
...
pushd "Full\Path\To\your\pdfTK\Folder\bin"
```

**2)** List your files by filtering the names of interest, already in order by date (old first) in one `for /f` loop:

```bath
dir /od /a:a /b
```

**3)** For each looped file, increment a counter to do inside a function already passing the pdf file path `"!_in_dir!\%%~i %%~j %%~k"`and the temporary folder `"!_out_dir!\."`
:

```bath
set /a "_cnt+=1" && call %:^) "%%~fi" "000!_cnt!" "!_out_dir!"
```

**4)** Your function `:label %:^)` will rename the files in numerical order to make it possible to concatenate by date order already move the file to its temporary folder in processing:

```bath
%:^)
...
set "_new=%~2" & call move "%~1" "%~3\!_new:~-4!.pdf"
```

**5)** After ending the loop in the pdf files, your temporary folder already contains the files of interest, so run `pdftk` to concatenate already saving/generating the desired file:

```bath
pushd "Full\Path\To\your\pdfTK\Folder\bin"
pdftk.exe "!_out_dir!\*.pdf" cat output "!_results!"
```

**6)** When in execution/processing you reach the `if` line, after finishing the `for /f` loop, your bat will remove the created folder and exit/close execution...

```bath
if not "%~nx1"=="" (...
     ) else (rmdir /s /q "!_out_dir!\." & popd & endlocal & goto :eOf)
```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [`Pushd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) | [`Popd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)
- [`Goto :Label` | `Call :Label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [`If condition() else condition()`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [DOS - String Manipulation // dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [How can I pass arguments to a batch file | *also applies to the function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-a-batch-file)